# Craft Assets on S3 bucket

Tags: assets, s3

Is there a way to use a local url when my assets are stored in an S3 bucket?

I have a bucket I'm pointing to and in there I have a folder called backgroundImg with a background.png

I'm trying to access this from my CSS like

`background-image: url('backgroundImg/background.png');`

But it cannot find this url. It's building the url `localhost/assets/backgroundImg/background.png`

Is there any way to use the local path instead of an insanely long s3 url that is hardcoded?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to build the complete URL to your file in order for it to work in your CSS.

See this answer:
[Do Remote Assets (ie. S3) have file paths?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12990/do-remote-assets-ie-s3-have-file-paths)

If the `background-image` is handled by something like a single or an entry template you could handle it with an inline style tag:

**Regular Loading:**
`{% set image = entry.backgroundImage.first()%}`

**Eager-loaded:**
`{% set image = entry.backgroundImage[0] ?? null%}`

**Template:**
`<main style="background-image: url({% if image %}{{image.url}}{% endif %});"></main>`